# VBA macro run-time too long

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I have written several subs which are then called from a main sub. Individual subs run very quickly, most are instantaneous (the DoFind sub takes a few seconds to run due to the large amounts of data in the table) however when I run the main sub it takes up to a minute to execute. Any ideas/tips on why this is the case?

Note, I haven't had much experience with VBA (all has been learnt in the past week). There are other macros used, but they are not shown since even the test sub takes approximately 1 minute

```
Sub DoFind()

    Dim i As Long

    i = 1

        Do While Sheets("Temp").Cells(i, "A").Value <> Empty

                Dim BearingArray(6) As String


                BearingArray(0) = Sheets("Temp").Cells(i, "A").Value
                BearingArray(1) = Sheets("Temp").Cells(i, "B").Value
                BearingArray(2) = Sheets("Temp").Cells(i, "C").Value
                BearingArray(3) = Sheets("Temp").Cells(i, "D").Value
                BearingArray(4) = Sheets("Temp").Cells(i, "E").Value
                BearingArray(5) = Sheets("Temp").Cells(i, "F").Value
                BearingArray(6) = Sheets("Temp").Cells(i, "G").Value


                With Sheets("Calculations")
                    .Cells(17, "K").Value = BearingArray(0)
                    .Cells(19, "O").Value = BearingArray(1)
                    .Cells(20, "O").Value = BearingArray(2)
                    .Cells(23, "O").Value = BearingArray(3)
                    .Cells(22, "O").Value = BearingArray(4)
                    .Cells(26, "O").Value = BearingArray(5)
                    .Cells(17, "L").Value = BearingArray(6)
                End With

                i = i + 1

                    If Sheets("Calculations").Cells(17, "M").Value = "PASS" Then
        Exit Do
                    Else
                    End If
        Loop
                    If Sheets("Temp").Cells(i, "A").Value = Empty Then
                        MsgBox "No available bearing."


                    End If


End Sub
```

---

```
Sub Create_Sheet_Temp()

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add
    ActiveSheet.Name = "Temp"

' This creates a new worksheet called "Temp"

End Sub
```

---

```
Sub Copy_Paste()

    Dim NewTable As ListObject
    Sheets("Calculations").Activate

    Set NewTable = Sheets("Calculations").ListObjects("Full_Bearings_List")

    NewTable.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
    NewTable.DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
    Sheets("Temp").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

        'This sub copies all visible cells from a filtered table and pastes them to the new sheet called "Temp"

End Sub
```

---

```
Sub test()
    Create_Sheet_Temp
    Copy_Paste
    DoFind

End Sub
```

Comment: If there is not an error, this question may be better placed over at [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Yeah there is no error so will also post the same question there, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can speed up your code by storing the worksheets in variables (ahead of the loop).

```
Dim TempWS as Worksheet
Dim CalcWS as Worksheet
set tempws= Sheets("Temp")
set CalcWS=Sheets("Calculations")
```

Also declare the array outside of the loop. Also Id recommend to use numeric column index.

```
Sheets("Temp").Cells(i, "G").Value
```

to 
    TempWS.Cells(i, 7).Value

Comparing against Empty is not always the best choice, try

```
... <> ""
```

EDIT:
For the Copy try t use the destination parameter of the Copy method. Example from the help:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:D4").Copy _ 
    destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("E5")
```